# AngularJS - Accessing the controller of a third party directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to use the [Search-Filter](http://ui.lumapps.com/components/search-filter) from the UI Framework [LumX](https://github.com/lumapps/lumX/tree/master/modules/search-filter) in what I admit is not traditional use.

The intended way the filter works is you press the magnifying glass button, it `opens`; calls method `openInput` on the controller.  The mouseout click closes it.

However I wish to extend this by `opening` and `closing` the input upon clicking on the `toolbar__label span` but my Angular knowledge is just not up to par yet.

My HTML looks like

```
<div class="toolbar" opensearch>
  <span class="toolbar__label fs-title ml black__text" >{{ "content.search.tip" | translate }}</span>
  <div class="toolbar__right">
    <lx-search-filter lx-width="400" lx-closed="true" >
      <input type="text" ng-model="vm.searchFilter.third">
    </lx-search-filter>
    <button class="btn btn--l btn--black btn--icon" lx-ripple>
      <i class="mdi mdi-apps"></i>
    </button>
  </div>
 </div>
```

If you open the github link, the `ng-click` of the directive itself is

```
ng-click="lxSearchFilter.openInput()"
```

My question is how can I access this `lxSearchFilter` controller from outside of the `lx-search-filter` directive?

I added my own directive `opensearch` and using the good old jquery way of things I can get it to work like:

```
link: function(scope, element) {
  element.bind('click', function(e) {
    var btn = angular.element(e.target).parent().find('button')[0];
    if (!isOpen) {
        isOpen = true;
        angular.element(btn).trigger('click');
      }
      return false;
    });
```

This does work with two caveats:

```
1. After a single open/close action I cannot reopen it
2. It's not the Angular way??
```

So again my question is how can I access this lxSearchFilter controller from outside of the lx-search-filter directive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the controller/link function of 3rd party directives by using `decorator`

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/decorators

You can use `.decorator` like `.controller` and put the code of `$provide.decorator` in the example inside it.

---

Edit: The way is to use `decorator` to extend it to support programatically open/close the search

https://jsbin.com/siceyeqeza/edit?html,js,output

Note that changing `$delegate[0].scope` only works when you have angular > 1.5.1 due to a bug https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/14785

Comment: I guess I should have phrased it better. I mean to trigger the lxSearchFilter.openInput() function, not modify it.  How can I trigger it from my own directive?

Comment: @lcycool wow! impressive.  I implemented this morning and works perfectly! Thanks very much

Comment: thanks for the compliment. Hope one day you can write as well. Happy coding!